# How to add a text view which is editable at runtime inside of a stack view programatically using uikit

Tags: swift, uikit

Stack view axis is horizontal. Stack view contains two views first is image view and other is custom text view. Namely Caption View. which basically contains a label and point of label is having placeholder functionality in text view.

This is caption view

```
import UIKit

class CaptionTextView: UITextView {
    private var placeHolderLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        configureUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func textChanged() {
        placeHolderLabel.isHidden = !text.isEmpty
    }

    private func configureUI() {
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        isScrollEnabled = false
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textChanged), name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        configurePlaceHolderLabel()
    }

    private func configurePlaceHolderLabel() {
        let label = UILabel()
        placeHolderLabel = label
        addSubview(label)
        label.text = "What's Happening?"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = .darkGray
        label.setTranslatesMask()
        let leading = label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 4)
        let top  = label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leading, top])
    }
}
```

this is where i am calling caption view

```
private func configureStackView() {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        contentView = stackView
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 16, bottom: 10, right: 16)
        stackView.spacing = 12
        stackView.setTranslatesMask()
        let leading = stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        let trailing = stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        let top = stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leading, trailing, top])
//        stackView.backgroundColor = .twitterBlue
        configureProfileImageView()
        configureCaptionView()
    }

    private func configureProfileImageView() {
        guard let url = URL(string: user.profileImageUrl) else { return }
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        contentView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        profileImageView = imageView
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        imageView.setTranslatesMask()
        let height = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
        let width = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([height, width])
    }

    private func configureCaptionView() {
        let captionView = CaptionTextView()
        contentView.addArrangedSubview(captionView)
        captionView.delegate = self
        self.captionTextView = captionView
    }

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

it is not letting me write sentence more than one line. Please help me. I started few months ago

Answer (score 1):

You *can* enter multiple lines of text. It's just that the height of the text view is not enough to show more than one line. You also disabled scrolling, which makes the text view unable to scroll to the bottom when a new line is entered, making it seem as if only one line can be entered.

The simple solution is to just enable scrolling.

If you want the text view to expand vertically when new lines are entered, you can add a height constraint to the text view, and adjust it every time the text changes.

```
// in CaptionTextView...
private var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

// in configureUI...
heightConstraint = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint!])

// in textChanged...
heightConstraint.constant = max(30, contentSize.height)
```

Note that I'm using 30 as the minimum height that the text view can get.

You could consider putting the `heightConstraint` as a property of the view controller. I put it in `CaptionTextView` simply because it is convenient to update it in `textChanged`.

In addition, you should also set the stack view's alignment to something other than `.fill`, e.g.

```
stackView.alignment = .top
```

Because the text view will have a different height than the image. The latter is constrained to 32. They can't *both* fill the height of the stack view.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After adding height consraint to caption view and changing  the alignment to top. I am able to enter lines upto the height. Somehow contentSize.height never changes. I am not very sure, but i think it is always the constant height which we provided. Due to which caption view does not increase in run time. Can you please help

Comment: @Pranjal can you edit your question  to show a [mcve], one that I can simply copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: @Pranjal Did you happen to `isScrollEnabled = false` by any chance? I just found that would break it. You should still set it to true. Practically, the text field is still not scrollable since its height is always at least its content size.